# Appending two databases with no common identifier

Tags: vba, excel, excel-formula

I have 3 datasets. I want to combnine the data in Database 1 and 2 organized by ID so that I can perform analysis on all variables in one place. In a separate sheet, I have matched the SSN to IDs, but they are not together on any of the main set. Also, the participant list in database 1 and database 2 are not equal.

My objective is to append database 1 and database 2, recognizing that they represent different populations. Thanks in advance.

```
Database1
SSN         CORTISOL    VITAMIN D
123143212   20          112
142342134   11          543

Database2
ID           Rbans      pcl
B1234        43         32
C4325        54         53

Database3
SSN         ID  
123143212   B1234         
142342134   C4325
```

Comment: Is there any link between the 2 datasets? How do you match the SSN ans the ID?

Comment: This would be easier in sql or access.

Comment: How big are these data sets?

Comment: On what basis you want to merge databases?

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If I understand correctly you want to add CORTISOL, Vitamin D as well as Rbans and pcl next to the appropriate ID/SSL identifiers in dataset 3. Is that right? Usually people write what they have tried first, and also give an example of desired result, not only input data.

Comment: Something like `SELECT * FROM Database1 A LEFT JOIN Database3 B ON A.SSN = B.SSN LEFT JOIN Database2 C ON B.ID = C.ID` would be the direction I'd start with.

Comment: @comintern this is a great Idea. Database 3 is something I created to match the SSN and IDs, I didn't think of joining both other sets to this one.

Comment: @ManishChristian I want to combine the entire content of set1 and set2, but I lack a common identifier in them. I created set 3, which links the two. It appears comintern has a good place for me to start

Comment: So what would be your final result look like? Database 3...?

Comment: @ManishChristian Yes-- So the plan now is to bring all data from set1 to set 3 and join by SSN. And then bring all data from set 2 to set 3 and join by ID.

Comment: @DavidG Sorry David, I was unable to wrap my head around this because I planned to join set1 & set2 but bringing them to set 3 makes more sense. What do you think of this?

Comment: @Nadeem_MK I made set3 independently so that I could eventually link the actual data. Does it make sense to you to bring both other sets to set3 ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Consider an SQL solution as this is a straighforward inner join query and Excel VBA can run SQL on its own, opened workbook connecting via ADO to the Jet/ACE SQL Engine (Windows .dll files, usually installed on all PC machines).

Below macro assumes four sheets exists in one workbook: *[Database1$]*, *[Database2$]*, *[Database3$]*, and a blank *[Results$*] with data columns starting in *A1* cell.

**SQL** query *(inserted in VBA as string)*

```sql
SELECT d1.SSN, d2.ID, d1.CORTISOL, 
       d1.[VITAMIN D], d2.Rbans, d2.pcl
FROM (Database3 d3 INNER JOIN Database2 d2 ON d3.ID = d2.ID) 
INNER JOIN Database1 d1 ON d3.SSN = d1.SSN;
```

[image: Database Joins Diagram]

**VBA** macro *(two connections strings available)*

```
Sub RunSQL()

    Dim conn As Object, rst As Object
    Dim strConnection As String, strSQL As String
    Dim i As Integer, fld As Object

    Set conn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
    Set rst = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

     ' STRING VALUES
'    strConnection = "DRIVER={Microsoft Excel Driver (*.xls, *.xlsx, *.xlsm, *.xlsb)};" _
'                      & "DBQ=C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm;"
    strConnection = "Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0;" _
                       & "Data Source='C:\Path\To\Workbook.xlsm';" _
                       & "Extended Properties=""Excel 8.0;HDR=YES;"";"

    strSQL = "SELECT d1.SSN, d2.ID, d1.CORTISOL," _
           & "       d1.[VITAMIN D], d2.Rbans, d2.pcl" _
           & " FROM ([Database3$] d3 INNER JOIN [Database2$] d2 ON d3.ID = d2.ID)" _
           & " INNER JOIN [Database1$] d1 ON d3.SSN = d1.SSN;" 

    ' OPEN DB CONNECTION AND RECORDSET
    conn.Open strConnection
    rst.Open strSQL, conn

    ' OUTPUT COLUMN HEADERS
    i = 0
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A1").Activate
    For Each fld In rst.Fields
        ActiveCell.Offset(0, i) = fld.Name
        i = i + 1
    Next fld

    ' OUTPUT DATA ROWS
    Worksheets("Results").Range("A2").CopyFromRecordset rst

    rst.Close
    conn.Close

End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

Say your database 1 is called Sheets("Db1") and the rest follow the same logic
Say the columns are A, B, and C for your examples.

```
Sub mergeDB
    Dim i as integer
    Dim lastlineDB3 as integer
    Dim strToMatch as string
    Dim FoundCell as range

    lastlineDB3 = Sheets("Db3").Range("A")(Sheets("Db3").Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Row

    for i = 2 to lastlineDB3
        strToMatch = Sheets("Db3").Range("A")(i).Value
        Set Foundcell= Sheets("Db1").Range("A:A").Find(strToMatch, Lookat:=xlWhole)
        If not Foundcell IS nothing then  
             'Now you have found a match for the SSN
             'What you have is the cell with the matching SSN (foundcell)
             'Write your own code here to decide what to do with that information
             'For example to grab the CORTISOL in column C (2 columns to the right)
             ' someString = FoundCell.Offset(0,2).Value
             'You can take all the values you have, I don't know how many you have so I'll let you write that part
             'Send those values over to the Db3 sheet where you want.
             'Hint: The row you want to send them at is row "i"
        End if
    next   

    'Once you matched all the SSNs do the same with the IDs

End sub
```